# Showing that a source is not Markov

Tags: coding-theory

If I have some source sending codewords and I take a large sample of codewords in order to construct an empirical distribution of the codewords sent. Using this empirical distribution, what methods can I use to demonstrate/prove (statistically) that the source is not a Markov source?

Comment: Please say more about the domain from which codewords are chosen.  Is it continuous ($\mathbb{R}^n$)?  Categorical (e.g., $\{0,1\}^n$)?  What do you mean by Markov source?  Do you mean that the sequence of numbers/bits in the codeword are generated from a Markov model, and each codeword is sampled iid from this same process?  Or that the sequence of codewords are generated from a  Markov model?

Comment: The domain is categorical and the sequence of messages are transmitted in a way such that is independent of what previous messages have been sent. So, for instance each message is independent of the message sent before it

Comment: Can you [edit] the question accordingly?  Thank you!